# Not able to go into the desktop, stuck in lock screen

Tags: system-installation

Few days back I tried to update my Dell XPS from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, the system got shut down before the upgradation was complete. When I boot the system again it just stays in the lock screen even if I enter the correct password.And the lock screen shows version 14.04 instead of 16.04 while the ubuntu screen shows it as 16.04. I have even tried booting with a different distro(using a live USB) but I get a boot error and operations system not found error. I am stuck as I have only one OS in the system.

I even get a 'failed to load kernel modules' error after booting.

Comment: Have you read why your question was closed?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best idea is to reinstall Ubuntu, but if you can´t you could try the recovery options during boot, by holding `Left Shift` during boot. But to me it sounds like you have messed up, mixed Ubuntu now. If you´d ask me, I would have done a reinstall.